# Перевод секунд в формат HH:MM:SS

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, математика, время

Нужна строка в формате часы:минуты:секунды
Подскажите алгоритм перевода секунд в такой формат или для этого есть методы?

Comment: Обьект Data позволяет сделать все переводы. Читайте справку https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @nick_n_a то, что нужно автору, не позволяет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function format(seconds) {
  let s = (seconds % 60).toString();
  let m = Math.floor(seconds / 60 % 60).toString();
  let h = Math.floor(seconds / 60 / 60 % 60).toString();
  return `${h.padStart(2,'0')}:${m.padStart(2,'0')}:${s.padStart(2,'0')}`;
}

console.log(format(3600));
```